# How to insert comma after 3 number in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-form

I am working on input , I want to insert comma after 3 number like ( 352,353,353 ) . I want to show it in text field . I am new to react could someone please help me how to achieve this goal .

**Code**

```
this.state = {
 phoneNumber:''
}

  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" value={this.state.phoneNumber} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **number.toLocaleString()**

Based on your example

```
this.state = {
 phoneNumber:''
}

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" value={this.state.phoneNumber} onChange={(e) => this.setState({phoneNumber: Number(e.target.value.replace(/,/g, '')).toLocaleString()})}/>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer , it updated state value but did not to access updated value in text field . it showing plain  not with comma

Comment: `<input type="text" placeholder="Enter text" value={this.state.phoneNumber} onChange={(e) => this.setState({phoneNumber: Number(e.target.value.replace(/,/g, '')).toLocaleString()})}/>` I updated the answer, now this should work.